# How to add gradients to a swatch in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, swatches

Is it possible to save gradients the same way one saves single colours (via creating a Swatch)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your gradient to the swatch library, then save the library as a separate file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Illustrator offers two options when saving the Swatch Library, as an AI or an ASE. Do you know what's the difference between AI and ASE?

Comment: For gradients its better to use the AI option. ASE seems to have limited support for gradients, also ASE seems to be used if you want to import your swatch library in another Adobe application.

Comment: More info here: http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1160237&seqNum=3

Answer (score 4):

Yep, just drag the gradient icon / preview from the gradient palette to the swatches palette:

[image]

Done.